# Why is the php session password being shown in a var_dump instead of the username?

Tags: php

I'm using the demo from this page: https://www.w3schools.in/php-script/php-login-without-using-database/ and if I add this to the index page:

```
<?php
var_dump($_SESSION);
?>
```

It's returning the password not the username and I can't figure out how to correct this.
Can anyone help please? I'd like to be able to display the name of the user who logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are storing:

```
$_SESSION['UserData']['Username']=$logins[$Username]
```

And that value you have already checked it:

```
logins[$Username] == $Password
```

So it is showing the password because you are **storing the password**.

If you want to store the username, then store `$Username`.

---

This is one more example of W3Schools being dreadful. I strongly suggest avoiding it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I didn’t know that about w3schools.
So do you mean change this:

  if (isset($logins[$Username]) && $logins[$Username] == $Password){

To this:

  if (isset($logins[$Username]) && $logins[$Username] == $Username){

If I do that the login fails.

Comment: @chipowski — No. Change what you are *storing*, not what you are *testing*

Comment: Isn't that what the existing code is doing here: $_SESSION['UserData']['Username']=$logins[$Username];

Comment: No. I already showed that `logins[$Username] == $Password`.

Comment: ah it just clicked what you're saying there. got it working properly now. thanks very much for your help